# Reviewing and displaying node reviews in Drupal 7

Tags: 7, nodes

I have to create a Movie content type that's going to be submitted by the Admin, but where anonymous users will have the possibility of adding a review.

As I'm using D7 (making NodeReview not an option), I was thinking of using the Vote API and fivestar.

My actual question is (and please excuse my n00bness): can I somehow embedded a "Review" content type (that's going to have fivestar, author name and a short text) in the Movie nodes and expose that to anonymous users?

Could someone point me what the Drupal way would be in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanted to do this very simply, you could just add a fivestar field to Drupal's built-in comments.  Comments already provides the author name and a description field (the comment), and enabling comments on nodes is easy (you can do it from structure/content types).

Comment: Thanks, I guess I could try something like that. Would displaying only the last 5 comments be possible though? Possibly creating a view for these content types that works contextually and somehow "grabbing" the comments to play with them?

Comment: Yes, you can use Views to easily show only the last five comments.  If you have trouble using Views just ask another question later.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot, I'm going to investigate both possibilities just for fun. Both seem feasible.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want use Drupal comment for any reason:
Use this modules:

1. [starrating](http://drupal.org/project/starrating) instead of fivestar, I think in this case it is better
2. [references](http://drupal.org/project/references)

create content type "Review", rename title field to Author, rename body field to note and configure it to accept just plain text, create a rate field of `starrating` type

finally create field_movie of `Node reference` type and set cardinality to 1.

use /node/add/review/xxx as Review creation link and alter Review creation form and set field_movie to xxx. xxx is Movie ID.

Comment: But if I need to alter the Review creation form I'm going to have to write a custom module...right?

Comment: Yes, very very small module...

Comment: I'm going to have to look more into that because I have never written one, but I guess you have to start somewhere... Thanks for the help, I gave the right answer to Patrick Kenny because he answered it first and upvotes to you because I can't pick two

Comment: in some case is need to have two stands of comment functionality, for example one for review movie and one for Q&A about movie, in those cases you should use Patrick Kenny way and mine together. otherwise Patrick Kenny is the only right solution

Comment: Having an exposed (and/or overwritten) form for certain custom content types is something I am very interested in doing even if not for this particular case. Do you have any links to how this is done?

Comment: All you want is here: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7 read comments also